# How to populate multi value parameter based on another parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have parameter `@Coverage` and parameter `@CoverageLosses`. They are NOT parent and child. I want default values for `@CoverageLosses` populated with values, based on `@Coverage`.
So my main dataset `@Coverage` looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Coverage
FROM            PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
ORDER BY Coverage
```

My secondary dataset `@CoverageLosses` looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Coverage AS CoverageLosses
FROM            tblLossesPlazaCommercialAuto
WHERE Coverage IN (@Coverage)
ORDER BY CoverageLosses
```

In report parameter `@CoverageLosses` I checked `Allow Multiple values` then in default-->`Specify values` I am writing this expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Coverage.Value="Liability","AutoLiabilityCLS" ,nothing)
```

It works fine for single value. But I want to see multiple values for `@CoverageLosses` if I choose `@Coverage = Liability`

How can I write the expression for that? Something like that:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Coverage.Value="Liability","AutoLiabilityCLS" & "AutoLiabilityCLS" & "AutoBodilyInjuryLiability"  ,nothing)
```

@CoverageLosses used for another table in my report. It will be hidden. But values from @Coverage will be mapped to values @CoverageLosses. So when user select, lets say value1 from @Coverage then default values in @CoverageLosses should be value1, value2,value3 etc

[image]

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to accomplish? Where and how is the parameter @coveragelosses used?

Comment: I edited explanation. for some reason its not allow me to post comment here

Comment: so, `@CoverageLosses` used for another table in my report. Parameter  will be hidden. But values from `@Coverage` will be mapped to values `@CoverageLosses`. So when user select, lets say value1 from `@Coverage` then default values in `@CoverageLosses` should be value1, value2,value3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an additional dataset and use it as your source for parameter:

```
select CoverageLosses from  (
select 'Liability' Coverage ,'AutoLiabilityCLS' CoverageLosses union 
select 'Liability' Coverage ,'AutoLiabilityCLS' CoverageLosses union 
select 'Liability' Coverage ,'AutoBodilyInjuryLiability' CoverageLosses union
select null Coverage ,null CoverageLosses  ) x
where Coverage = @Coverage
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kostya. 
Are you from San Diego?

Comment: The only thing is parameter values are not refreshed if I choosing from one value, back to `SELECT ALL` values. The correct values are populated, but not `checked`. I am using SQL server 2012. Visual Studio 2010.
   Do you know something about this issue?